# Sending HTTP request returns DOMException: A network error occurred

Tags: javascript

I am new to jscript. I am simply trying to connect to my api (which works on postman):

```
async function sendMSG() {
  var username = "username";
  var password = "xxx";
  var url = "https://api.kumulos.com/b2.2/xxx/getAllUsers.json";
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', url, false, username,password)
  await request.send()
}
```

but upon the line "send()", firefox gives me:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: A network error occurred.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: Avoid using `XMLHttpRequest`. Use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead. Especially if you are requesting JSON data.

Comment: Otherwise, XHR is not a Promise. You can wrap it if you really want to, but if you are in a browser supporting `async`-`await`, you can presumably use `fetch()`